# How to add a SPDK-backend OSD in Ceph (Octopus version)?

Tags: ceph, dpdk, nvme

I have an NVMe SSD and want to use it as an OSD backend, but I can't create an OSD when I want to enable SPDK(it could work as a block-device).

I did the following things:

1. Building Ceph with SPDK enabled

   I edit the CMakeLists.txt to make sure SPDK will be compiled:

```
CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION(WITH_SPDK "Enable SPDK" ON
"CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES i386|i686|amd64|x86_64|AMD64|aarch64" ON)
```

2. I set up my NVMe device by SPDK scripts and then test by:

```
$ sudo src/spdk/scripts/setup.sh 
 0000:0a:00.0 (8086 0a54): nvme -> vfio-pci
 $sudo src/spdk/scripts/setup.sh status
 $sudo src/spdk/examples/nvme/identify/identify
 $sudo src/spdk/examples/nvme/hello_world/hello_world
```

3. The output and test results looks good, but when I try to create OSD as [Ceph docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/configuration/bluestore-config-ref/), I meet errors:

```
 $sudo ceph-volume lvm create --bluestore --data spdk:0000.0a.00.0
 ceph-volume lvm create: error: argument --data: invalid <ceph_volume.util.arg_validators.ValidDevice object at 0x7fda562de1d0> value: 'spdk:0000.0a.00.0'
```

I try to replace the PCIe-id by serial number but the output is just the same, and I did some other tries but all failed...

And I found this description in [Ceph Documentation » ceph-volume » Overview](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/ceph-volume/intro/#ceph-volume-lvm):

> ceph-volume was designed to be a modular tool because we anticipate
> that there are going to be lots of ways that people provision the
> hardware devices that we need to consider. There are already two:
> legacy ceph-disk devices that are still in use and have GPT partitions
> (handled by simple), and lvm.
> SPDK devices where we manage NVMe devices directly from userspace are
> on the immediate horizon, where LVM won’t work there since the kernel
> isn’t involved at all.

So I wonder what should I do correctly or is SPDK not supported in Octopus()?

This troubled me for days and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I believe you answered your own question, it's on the horizon but not possible yet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that... I saw the SPDK part in the Luminous codes and from the BlueStore's doc, SPDK looks supported. I'm going to try other methods... Thanks for your help!